# How to output between two xml tags?

Tags: java, php, xml, tags

I have never seen tagging like this:

```
<verse sID=".1.1" osisID=".1.1" /> data data <verse eID=".1.1"/>
```

because I think it should be like this:

```
<verse osisID=".1.1"> data data </verse>
```

The problem is that I'm trying to output texts between `<verse/> texts <verse/>.`
I have lots of xml to disply texts between such open and close tags. It would work if `<verse> texts </verse>`.
How to code in Java or PHP to output texts between these tags. I have coded it in PHP.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("go.xml");

foreach ($xml->osisText->div->p->verse as $verse) {
   echo $verse."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

It does not work. I haven't tried in Java.
Below is sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osis xmlns="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace http://www.bibletechnologies.net/osisCore.2.1.1.xsd">
    <osisText xml:lang="en">
        <chapter sID=".1" osisID=".1"/>
        <div type="section">
            <p>
                <verse sID=".1.1" osisID=".1.1" />
                Hello Verse One
                <verse eID=".1.1" osisID=".1.1" />
                <verse sID=".1.2" osisID=".1.2" />
                Hello Verse Two
                <verse eID=".1.2" osisID=".1.2" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <verse sID=".1.3" osisID=".1.3" />
                Hello Verse One
                <verse eID=".1.3" osisID=".1.3" />
                <verse sID=".1.4" osisID=".1.4" />
                Hello Verse Two
                <verse eID=".1.4" osisID=".1.4" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </osisText>
</osis>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is regex

```
    String s = "<verse sID=\".1.1\" osisID=\".1.1\" /> data data <verse eID=\".1.1\"/>"; 
    s = s.replaceAll("<verse .+ />(.+)<verse .+/>", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
 data data
```

Comment: I have validated all xml at w3c.org .The result is valid. And your answer help how to replace the xml tags. Thank you.

Comment: You answer seems to imply that this xml is not well formed, when it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
function extractContents($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = stripos($string, $start);
    $str = substr($string, $pos);
    $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
    $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);
    $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);
    $extractedContents = trim($str_three);
    return $extractedContents;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
$start = '/>';
$end = '<verse';
$contents = extractContents($string, $start, $end)
```